# iPhone 4s iOS 6 - how to clear Location Services memory

Tags: iphone, ios

I was viewing a site that asked for permission to access my location which I declined. Since then the site never asks again, it seems like the iPhone has remembered my choice so automatically declines.

Location Services are enabled and enabled for Safari. I have tried closing safari (from task manager) and disable/re-enable Location Services, rebooted iPhone.

If I view the site on a desktop in Firefox or other browser, it asks for location access everytime I refresh (even if I decline everytime) so I know it's not the site that's the problem.

My question is, is there any way to clear this "memory" that the iPhone has seemingly stored? Perhaps clearing Safari history would do it but I want to avoid that if possible.

Edit: Clearing Safari history and cookies doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reset your location preferences, do the following:

1. From your Home screen, go to **Settings > General > Reset**
2. Select **Reset Location & Privacy**

Note: This will reset your location warnings for all sites and applications.